# Size UITextView to contents in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have seen and tried a few solutions online to size a text view to its contents but nothing seems to be working. I have auto layout on, scrolling disabled, and here is the code in viewDidLoad I'm using to try and resize the text view dynamically.

```
var frame = aboutText.frame
    frame.size.height = aboutText.contentSize.height
    aboutText.frame = frame
```

I have also tried

```
aboutText.sizeToFt()
aboutText.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Edit: Also tried:

```
let fixedWidth = aboutText.frame.size.width
    aboutText.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    let newSize = aboutText.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    var newFrame = aboutText.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    aboutText.frame = newFrame
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, because you are using auto layout, you should be able to use constraints and compression/stretching priorities to set the text view to size to its contents. This is a text view's natural behavior.

However, if this should fail, here is the code that should force it to size to its content:

```
let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(width,  CGFloat(FLT_MAX)))
// where width is the width that the text view should be, usually width of parent view - 20
textView.frame = CGRectMake(textView.frame.origin.x, textView.frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height)
// you may have to call view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

UPDATE ** Auto textView sizing for UITableView

Implement this in your UITableViewDelegate:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Then constrain the text view to the top and bottom of the table view cell.  With this each table view cell should resize to fit it's content text.

This video should address your problem exactly, it helped me a lot:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=231

Comment: Thanks, I added that in and no luck :( think it might be something else on my end I have set incorrectly?

Comment: It depends. Is the text view in UIView? Is the text being cut off or is the text view too large?

Comment: The text view is in a tableView cell and yes it's cut off

Comment: Oh its in a tableView!  That's a big difference.  I'll update my answer with something that should work.